# Doing math with elements of a 2d-array?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, multidimensional-array

So I am making a 2d-array like this:

```
var kcalVerdier:Array = new Array(92,80,103,36,53);
var alleNumSteppers:Array = new    Array(alleNumSteps.numStepMelk.value,alleNumSteps.numStepEgg.value,alleNumSteps.numStepBrød.value,alleNumSteps.numStepSmør.value,alleNumSteps.numStepOst.value);
var c:Array = new Array(kcalVerdier,alleNumSteppers);
function endreAntall(evt:Event)
{


        txtTotalKcal.text = String(c[0] * [0]);




}
```

Is it not possible to do multiply 2 values of a 2-d Array? I get this error:

Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 17, Column 38    1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Array to an unrelated type Number.

I don't understand why, c[0][0] should both be  integer values or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: But you didn't create a 2D Array, `c` is an Array that has all the values of `kcalVerdier` and `alleNumSteppers`.

Comment: Both are Arrays, so it's c is Array of Arrays.

Comment: So it is a 2d-array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which values you actually want to multiply?
By doing:

```
c[0] * [0]
```

you're trying to multiply Array by Array.

`c[0]` would be 1st element of `c` Array which is in fact `kcalVerdier` Array.
`[0]` is making new Array with one element (that is 0);

so it's like
`[92,80,103,36,53] * [0]`

**[EDIT]**

Ok, try this piece of code:

```
// Check if both Arrays are what we want:
trace("kcalVerdier => " + c[0]);
trace("alleNumSteppers => " + c[0]);
trace();

// Gett Arrays lengths
var arr1Length:int = c[0].length;
var arr2Length:int = c[1].length;

// Check if both are the same length
if(arr1Length == arr2Length)
{
    // Let's iterate
    for(var i:int = 0; i<arr1Length; i++)
    {
        trace( c[0][i] * c[1][i] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh I see... Ideally I would want to multiply every value in kcalVerdier with the the right numeric stepper so [0] in KcalVerdier *  [0] in alleNumSteppers and [1 ] * [1] and so forth.  But in what I posted I tried to multiply just 92 * alleNumSteps.numStepMelk.value

I guess the way to do what I actually want I have to use a double for loop inside the function or?

Comment: ok, maybe try: for(i:int = 0; i<c[0].length; i++) trace(c[0][i] * c[1][i]); Beware tho. It's gonna explode if second array is shorter than first one.

[EDITED]
should be `i<c[0].length` instead of `i<c[0][0].length`

Comment: Yes i tried but it didn't work was trying to figure out why but didn't understand.

Comment: Also I can't declare the variable in the for loop like you I get a syntax error with the colon. But it works when I declare it outside and leave  `i = 0;` inside. I don't know if I am missing something but it only outputs five zeros when I trace it, no matter what value my numeric steppers has.